# Read manufacture data of ble packet with javascript

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, packet-capture

I am working on a React-native ble project that now requires a Broadcaster (device) observer (client) relationship.

Is there a high level (JavaScript) way of reading the advertisement packet of ble to obtain the byte array? I am trying to read the entire advertisement packet rather than any format.

I have use react-native-ble-manager and am looking at react-native-ble-plx by Polidea:

https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/#devicemanufacturerdata

It looks as if specific fields of the advertisement packet are available under Device: such as manufacture data (the thing I am most interested in and manipulating on the embedded side). However, Most of Polidea examples obtain the Device from a connection.

I may be misinterpreting the documentation? Could use some advice/ direction to any further references.

Answer (score 0):

Was misunderstanding the documentation..

2 minutes of stripping down some complexity revealed what I needed to know.

Answer provided for reference of others:

BleManager's startDeviceScan function(UUIDS, options, listener) where listener is the function where second argument is returned device object. Access its fields from there.

```
this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    return;
  }
  if(device.name === "Some_encoding_Sensor_1"){
    console.log(device.manufacturerData);
  }
```

Example shown should filter based off of UUID rather than device.name but that may be easier to work with initially/dynamically (having multiple devices with renaming scheme).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this JS library:
[advlib](https://github.com/reelyactive/advlib)

It helps with advertising packet decoding and currently supports the following protocols:

1. Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)
2. reelyActive RFID